# CreatePushAsync not working: VssServiceException: The parameters supplied are not valid. Parameter name: newPush

Tags: c#, rest, azure-devops

I am trying to replicate the post request as given in the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#update_a_file

using the .Net libraries for making an extension.

I have checked that the refUpdate and OldObjectId are correct through trial and error.
changes, item, repo are all defined and not null.

```
   GitPush push = new GitPush();
   GitCommit gitCommit = new GitCommit();
   GitChange change = new GitChange();
   ItemContent content = new ItemContent();
   content.Content = changeString;
   content.ContentType = ItemContentType.RawText;
   change.NewContent = new ItemContent();
   change.ChangeType = VersionControlChangeType.Edit;
   change.Item = item;
   List<GitChange> changes = new List<GitChange>();
   changes.Add(change);
   gitCommit.Changes = changes;
   gitCommit.Comment = "updated app.cpp";
   GitRefUpdate refUpdate = new GitRefUpdate();
   refUpdate.Name = "refs/heads/dev";
   refUpdate.OldObjectId = oldObjectId;
   List<GitCommit> commits = new List<GitCommit>();
   commits.Add(gitCommit);
   List<GitRefUpdate> refUpdates = new List<GitRefUpdate>();
   refUpdates.Add(refUpdate);
   push.Commits = commits;
   push.RefUpdates = refUpdates;
   GitPush pushed = gitClient.CreatePushAsync(push, repo.Id).Result;
```

On the last line the debugger gives the exception that parameter "newPush" is not defined.